# NullPointerException in my code but can't figure out why

Tags: java, cardlayout

I'm writing a program for my school assignment using CardLayout() but I keep getting a null pointer error but I can't figure out why. Can someone please point out the error in my code. The code is incomplete but applet opens and displays buttons but not the card.

The error I get is when I press the Input button (so it's in the ActionListener):

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at BookCentre.actionPerformed(BookCentre.java:162)

```
//removed code since assignment is due in a week.
```

Comment: what's on line 162 in your code? I'd imagine it's that you never initialize CardDeck1. I don't see that anywhere in the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is -as @mike suggest- that CardDeck1 variable is never initialized. I initialize it in the declaration only for testing purposes, you must do it in the neccesary part of the code, where you really need it.

```
    //Only for testing purposes
    // Create JPanel deck and add cards to it
    deck = new JPanel();
    CardDeck1 = new CardLayout();
    deck.setLayout(CardDeck1);
    deck.add(inputCard(), INPUT);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Oh such a simple error. Thanks so much! This error gave me a headache for two days.

Comment: Nice to hear it works for you!! Greetings since Mexico City!